# Using Vlookup from a VBA module in Excel to check if value is in table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range in a worksheet, and I want to check whether the value a user enters into a different cell of a different worksheet is in that range.  If the value is not in that range (i.e., the user entered an incorrect value), I want to flag a test field to alert the user.  I am doing this as part of a larger validation function.

This works if the value is in the range, but if it is not, the function throws an error (without alerting me) and exits

```
 Public Function ValidateField(dataValue as Range) as Integer
     Dim result As Variant

     Dim sheet As Worksheet
     Dim range As range

     Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Menu")
     Set range = sheet.range("BC141:BD175")


     result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDec(dataValue), range, 1, False)

     'this does not work
     If InStr(CStr(result), "Error") > 0 Or result = "" Then
        ValidateField = 1
        Exit Function
     End If
     If CDec(result) <> CDec(dataValue) Then
        ValidateField = 1
        Exit Function
     End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
'~~> Check if `CDec(dataValue)` exists in Column BC
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng.Columns(1), CDec(dataValue)) = 0 Then
    '
    '~~> Not Found... Do Something
    '
    Exit Function
End If
```

This would go before

```
result = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CDec(dataValue), range, 1, False)
```

BTW I noticed something. You are using `1` in `Vlookup`. If you want to just check if the value is in Col `BC` or not then you don't need `Vlookup`. You can use `CountIf` for that purpose.